# Demonstrate $A \subseteq P(\cup A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a set

$P(A)=\{B|B\subseteq A \}$

$ \cup A = \{x | \exists a \in A, x\in a \} $

My try:

If $C\subseteq A$ if there is $x\in C$, tal que $x\in \cup A$

then $x\subseteq P(\cup A)$

I fell like this last step is not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x\in A:$ you want to prove that it is an element of $\mathcal{P}(\cup A),$ so you prove that $A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\cup A).$

Actually you can write $x$ as $\{a\in\cup A| a\in x\}.$ From this point of view it is clear that $x$ is a subset of $\cup A$ and so it belongs to the set $\mathcal{P}(\cup A).$

Comment: But by definition $\cup A$ does not have any subsets, they are just elements.  For example: $A=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ then $\cup A=\{1,2,3\}$. What do you think? }

Comment: @SebasMartinezSantos You are correct that $\bigcup A = \{1,2,3\}$ in your example.  You say "*by definition $\bigcup A$ does not have any subsets...*" Every set has subsets, including those sets which are sets of sets or otherwise.  In your example $\bigcup A$ has the following eight subsets: $\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\}\dots,\{1,2,3\}$.  As such the power set of $\bigcup A$ would be $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\dots,\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.  You may have meant to say $\bigcup A$ does not have any sets *as elements*, which has a different meaning.

Comment: Exactly, be careful Sebas that an element of A can be a set itself.